# Subscription code (setInterval) of a component is still running so I get out of this

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, subscribe

I have a subscript (works as a setInterval) that executes a code every 10 seconds in a component named "coordinator-component.ts". Until then everything is fine, the problem I have is the following:
When I pass from one url to another, the subscription is still running, which should not happen, since this should only be executed in the view and component of the "coordinator-component". I do not know if it is saved in cache, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: you can call unsubscribe() on observables and better call them during ngOnDestroy on components

Comment: Yep that is a memory leak https://www.agiratech.com/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-angular-observables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you using an `Observable`, when you `subscribe()` it return a `Subscription` and the best practice is to store the `Subscription` to a variable and unsubscribe() to it during
`ngOnDestroy()`

```
export class YourComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  yourStoredSubscription: Subscription;

  // You subscribe to it somewhere in your code for example and it return a subscription
  ngOnInit() {
     this.yourStoredSubscription = this.yourSetInterval.subscribe();   
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.yourStoredSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```